# Start loading the second row after the second image on the first row has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I would like to do is have the second row of image start loading after the second image on the first has loaded. Currently it waits for the first row to fully load all 10 images, how would I trigger this?

This is an example url
http://satbulsara.com/experiment-04/

and this is my code

```
var delay = 200, t = 0;
$("#rowOne").children('li').css('display', 'none').each(function(){
  t += delay;
  var $li = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $li.fadeIn(1900);
  },t);
});

$("#rowTwo").children('li').css('display', 'none').each(function(){
  t += delay;
  var $li = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $li.fadeIn(1900);
  },t);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `t = delay * 2;` before the code for the second row to set the initial delay for it.

```
var delay = 200, t = 0;
$("#rowOne").children('li').css('display', 'none').each(function(){
  t += delay;
  var $li = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $li.fadeIn(1900);
  },t);
});

t = delay * 2;

$("#rowTwo").children('li').css('display', 'none').each(function(){
  t += delay;
  var $li = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $li.fadeIn(1900);
  },t);
});
```

To make it suitable for multiple rows (also, don't repeat yourself):

```
var delay = 200, t = 0;
$(".row").each(function() { 
  $(this).children('li').css('display', 'none').each(function(
  {
    t += delay;
    var $li = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $li.fadeIn(1900);
    },t);
   });
   t = delay * 2;
});
```

And add `class="row"` to the `<ul>` elements.

Comment: almost but it has a weird delay now that isn't the desired effect

Comment: as it loads all images in the first row.

Comment: You have to put a `<br style="clear: both" />` or something like that between the two rows, so that all the images won't just be floated next to eachother, but in separate rows.

Comment: excellent that works for the 2 rows but what if i wanted to add another row?

Comment: out of curiousity how could i get it to start from the right hand side?

Comment: it took the <br /> out and just applied clear both to the <ul> works fine still, thanks Yasik!!